# При масштабировании страницы текст вылезает за блок

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы текст не вылезал за блок при масштабировании страницы?

```css
.content p {}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 715px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: url(pattern-bg.png);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #000;
}

.mini-content-bg {
  padding: .3em .6em;
  background: #0C306D;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

.content>div+div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.mini-content {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10);
  border-radius: 2em;
}

.mini-content p {
  margin: 0;
}


/* -content-1- */

.mini-content-1 {
  grid-template-areas: "mini-img mini-h3 mini-h3 mini-h3 ." "mini-img mini-txt mini-txt mini-txt mini-txt2" "mini-img . . mini-a .";
}

.mini-content-1 .mini-img {
  grid-area: mini-img;
}

.mini-content-1 h3 {
  grid-area: mini-h3;
}

.mini-content-1 .mini-txt {
  grid-area: mini-txt;
}

.mini-content-1 a {
  grid-area: mini-a;
}

.mini-content-1 .mini-txt2 {
  grid-area: mini-txt2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">

  <div class="content">

    <div class="mini-content-bg">
      <div class="mini-content-1 mini-content">
        <p class="mini-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.mgtk.kz/_nw/1/44613246.jpg" width="170" height="125"></a>
        </p>

        <h3><a href="#">Гранты по специальностям</a></h3>

        <p class="mini-txt">Государственный образовательный заказ на подготовку специалистов с техническим и профессиональным, послесредним образованием на 2019-2020 учебный год...</p>

        <a href="#">ПОДРОБНО</a>

        <p class="mini-txt2">03.07.19, 11:10<br> Просмотров: 355</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас для класса `.mini-content` жестко установлена высота = 150px (`height: 150px`). При этом, высота содержимого в строках грида и промежутков между строками суммарно превышает 150px. Поэтому и вылезает частично.

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос (Как сделать так, чтобы текст не вылезал за блок), можно посоветовать убрать жесткое ограничение высоты для `.mini-content`

```css
.content p {}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 715px;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;



    padding: 1.5em;

    background: url(pattern-bg.png);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #000;
}

.mini-content-bg {
    padding: .3em .6em;

    background: #0C306D;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.content > div + div {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.mini-content {
    /* height: 150px; */
    padding: 1em;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;

    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10);
    border-radius: 2em;
}

.mini-content p {
    margin: 0;
}

/* -content-1- */

.mini-content-1 {
    grid-template-areas: "mini-img mini-h3 mini-h3 mini-h3 ."
        "mini-img mini-txt mini-txt mini-txt mini-txt2"
        "mini-img . . mini-a .";
}



.mini-content-1 .mini-img {
    grid-area: mini-img;
}

.mini-content-1 h3 {
    grid-area: mini-h3;
}

.mini-content-1 .mini-txt {
    grid-area: mini-txt;
}

.mini-content-1 a {
    grid-area: mini-a;
}

.mini-content-1 .mini-txt2 {
    grid-area: mini-txt2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">

    <div class="content">

        <div class="mini-content-bg">
            <div class="mini-content-1 mini-content">
                <p class="mini-img"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.mgtk.kz/_nw/1/44613246.jpg" width="170" height="125"></a></p>

                <h3><a href="#">Гранты по специальностям</a></h3>

                <p class="mini-txt">Государственный образовательный заказ на подготовку специалистов с техническим и профессиональным, послесредним образованием на 2019-2020 учебный год...</p>

                <a href="#">ПОДРОБНО</a>

                <p class="mini-txt2">03.07.19, 11:10<br>
                    Просмотров: 355</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это исправило проблему, но теперь при масштабировании страницы этот самый блок просто расширяется под размер контента в нём и получается какой-то квадрат. Как сделать так, чтобы при масштабировании страницы этот блок оставался уменьшался в соответствии с масштабом страницы и текст в нём тоже?

Comment: если вас правильно понял, прочитайте про max-width, min-width, max-height, min-height

Answer (score 0):

В общих чертах обернул информационный текст в , чтобы не разводить всякие grid-area и прочие ненужные стили. И потом поделил с помощью grid-template-columns на три столбца и всё встало хорошо. height поставил на auto, так как height никогда не должен быть определённого размера, если вы не используете overflow.

```css
.content p {}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: url(pattern-bg.png);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #000;
}

.mini-content-bg {
  padding: .3em .6em;
  background: #0C306D;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

.content>div+div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.mini-content {
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10, #436B10, #6FB119, #436B10);
  border-radius: 2em;
}

.mini-content p {
  margin: 0;
}


/* -content-1- */

.mini-content-1 {
  grid-template-columns: 170px auto 125px;
  align-items: center;
}
.mini-content-1 h3 a {
  text-align: left;
}
.mini-content-1 .mini-img {
  align-self: start;
}
.mini-content-1 a {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">

  <div class="content">

    <div class="mini-content-bg">
      <div class="mini-content-1 mini-content">
        <p class="mini-img">
          <a href="#"><img src="http://www.mgtk.kz/_nw/1/44613246.jpg" width="170" height="125"></a>
        </p>
        <div class="wrapper-info">
          <h3><a href="#">Гранты по специальностям</a></h3>

          <p class="mini-txt">Государственный образовательный заказ на подготовку специалистов с техническим и профессиональным, послесредним образованием на 2019-2020 учебный год...</p>

          <a href="#">ПОДРОБНО</a>
        </div>

        <p class="mini-txt2">03.07.19, 11:10<br> Просмотров: 355</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```